# Pass through `IHttpHandler` response on error

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-error, custom-errors

So, IIS is pissing me off. It keeps on screwing with my error handling. I have a number of `IHttpHandlers` registered, and they're doing a good job. When I connect locally, I get the response I expect. But when I connect remotely, IIS's `CustomErrorModule` starts interfering. I've played with `system.webServer/httpErrors` and `ssytem.web/customErrors` to no avail. The only thing that works is `system.webServer/modules/remove@name=CustomErrorModule`, but that requires setting `lockItem="false"` for `CustomErrorModule` in the system's `applicationHost.config` file. Which is not a solution I like.

Is there some way to *entirely* disable `CustomErrorModule` without messing with any system files? I.e. without having admin privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! In `<system.webServer>`:

`<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />`

This does *exactly* what I want.